# Como executar o comando JOIN em ORACLE?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Olá. Estou tendo problemas com a minha consulta no ORACLE, alguém saberia me dizer como resolve-la ?

```
SELECT C.NRO_CONTA, C.NOME, C.SALDO, SUM(RESULTADO.COTAS) FROM CONTA C 
JOIN FUNDOS_APLIC AS RESULTADO
ON  RESULTADO = ( SELECT SUM(FAP.NRO_COTAS) AS COTAS FROM FUNDOS_APLIC FAP WHERE FAP.NRO_CONTA = C.NRO_CONTA  GROUP BY FAP.NRO_CONTA, FAP.COD_FUNDO   )
```

Quando tento executar a Query o resultado é o seguinte : SQL Error [905] [42000]: ORA-00905: palavra-chave não encontrada

Se alguém poder me ajudar, ou me ensinar uma maneira mais simples de conseguir efetuar a consulta, agradeço.

Comment: O que vem a ser Fg? Para obter SUM(FA.RESULTADO) deve existir um GROUP BY em seu SELECT mais externo.

Comment: tente FROM FUNDOS_APLIC fg

Comment: Estou achando meio confuso o fato de você ter duas consultas na mesma tabela com o mesmo nome, onde uma vc renomeou e outra não, tente renomear a tabela FUNDOS_APLIC que realiza o SUM(NRO_COTAS)

Comment: Editei o código com as dicas que vocês me deram (editei ele lá em cima). Mas o resultado continua sendo o mesmo.